# Protect content uploaded by a specific user in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm follwing the [upload tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) on Symfony 2 website and I'm going to upload to:

```
web/uploads/{user_salt}/{upload_unique_random_name}.ext
```

This is fine for public accessible files. But how can I protect certain files? For example, in an upload form, user can make the file "public" or "private". How should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't expose the files publicly, instead I would store them in a private location (outside of the `web` directory), create a Bundle and a Controller, and in the controller have an action which takes a file ID and looks up its access level from a database table. If the file is publicly accessible, serve it. If not, then make sure the user has permissions to view the file.

You just need to create a `File` entity, and a table which stores permissions for users or user roles against those files so that you can cross-check them upon request.

It will add some overhead to serving the files though, as a full Symfony2 request will need to take place, whereas serving files straight over apache or nginx won't have the overhead of the framework stack.

Hopefully I've explained that well enough.

EDIT:

If you're serving these images via the use of a token (e.g. via an email) then you can do something along the lines of the following...

Example Image `src` attribute: http://yourdomain.com/assets/12/TOKEN

This route config would look something like this (in YAML):

```yaml
assets_serve:
    pattern: /assets/{id}/{token}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeAssetBundle:Assets:serve }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

In your `AcmeAssetBundle`, you'll have an `AssetsController` with a `serve` action:

```php
class AssetController extends Controller
{
    public function serveAction($id, $token = null)
    {
        //fetch asset record from the database -- which also contains its file path
        //check the TOKEN matches the one stored against this image
        //set content-type headers and serve the image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks foy your answer. The problem is that those files (at least, those public) are used as images in emails (`src` attribute) and should be public.

Comment: This shouldn't matter, I'll edit my answer to explain a bit better

Comment: Good exmplaination. Sounds a good solution to me. Last 2 quesitons: which folder should store the images? maybe `app/Resources/assets`? And why there is the need of token? I can simply point the url to /assets/2324, check if public or check if user it's the owner. Can't get the point of token...

Comment: If you're serving images via email, but don't want regular joes trying to guess the image ID and hitting the asset URL, the token will stop them from doing so. When you generate the image src attribute for the email body text, you can output the token as part of it. That directory sounds like a sensible location to me

Comment: So, what's location do you suggest?

Comment: As I said in my last comment, the `app/Resources/assets` location sound sensible enough to me, but anywhere outside of your bundles and web directories :)

Comment: @Jaitsu How do you access files stored outside the web directory? Do you use a php function to send files that are not accessible through an HTTP request?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is your friend here, you can get the file contents from any file on the file system (providing the web user has read privileges) and then you can send the correct content-type header and echo out the file contents

Comment: How about if the image is display in external front end like in react ?

Comment: I don't see how that's any different? You use the same image URL